# trouble with unhandled promise

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise, async-await, mean-stack

Here is part of my code, that has a problem:

```js
router.route('/mate/add').post(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let mate = await mate.save();
    res.status(200).json({
      'mate:': 'Added succesfully'
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send('failed to create');
  }
});
```

After compiling I get:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)

Why does this happen?

Comment: Most likely `res.status(400).send('failed to create');` threw an exception. You should also get the error message itself next to the warning.

Comment: just try to console.log(err). And check the error.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone, seems to me i got it